# How to pass configuration through aliases .sbtrc

Tags: sbt

I would like to create aliases in sbtrc along with the config file that it needs to use.

For ex:

```
alias run-web-dev = ;web;~ run -Dconfig.resource=dev.conf
alias run-web-qa = ;web;~ run -Dconfig.resource=qa.conf
```

so that I can just run

```
./activator run-web-dev to use dev.conf and  
./activator run-web-qa to use qa.conf
```

Is something like this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up aliases in your [global.sbt file](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Global-Settings) as follows:

```
addCommandAlias("run-web-dev", ";web;~ run -Dconfig.resource=dev.conf")
```